# Django translations: setting of LANGUAGE_CODE working - accept-languages not?

Tags: django

I'm trying to fix translations for a little Django project of mine. Unsing Django 2.2.12.

Current status is, that I can switch translations by setting LANGUAGE_CODE to different values. But I would like to switch translations by means of accept-language of browser - which does not seem to work. My suspicion is, that for some reason the middleware is not configured correctly.

This is what I have set for middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And languges:

```
LANGUAGES = (
('de', 'German'),
('tr', 'Turkish'),
('en', 'English'),
('it', 'Italian'),
('fr', 'French'),
)
```

From the documentation I conclude, that if setting of LANGUAGE_CODE changes the translation - as is the case for me - then all other means of determining the proper translation have failed (including cookies). Because LANGUAGE_CODE is evaluated in the last step.

I would like to know how I could check it the middleware is doing it's thing correclty - and why it seems to ignore accept-language. Any hints on this are highly appreciated!

Comment: It works, but if a cookie is set, then this overrides the value for `Accept-languages`.

Comment: There are several ways that Django tries to determine the language to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference. Have you added the language to `settings.LANGUAGES`?

Comment: Have edited my question to incorporate the comments - thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `settings.USE_I18N=True`, the key codes are in `django.utils.translation.trans_real.get_language_from_request()` function
which is called by `LocaleMiddleware.process_request()`.
language_code is found out with priority from high to low as below.

firstly, if urlconf is handled by i18n_patterns function, it will respect the explicit language_code info in path.

```
lang_code = get_language_from_path(request.path_info)
```

if not or invalid, as respecting user, then try getting language_code out of request.session which could be set it somewhere,
and usually client could post {language:'en'} to the url path of django.views.i18n.set_language(request).

```
lang_code = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY) # LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY = '_language'
```

if not or invalid, then try getting language_code out of request.cookies as respecting client.

```
lang_code = request.COOKIES.get(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME) # LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
```

if not or invalid, then try getting the first valid language_code out of ACCEPT_LANGUAGE as respecting browser.

```
accept = request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', '')  # usually it has a lot of language info
```

if invalid, else:

```
lang_code = get_supported_language_variant(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

So, you can print all the related info to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my findings based on the answer of @Blackdoor:

- `django.utils.translation.trans_real.get_language_from_request()` returns "en"
- `django.utils.translation.get_language_from_path(request.path_info)` returns None
- `request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)` leads to an AttributeError: "'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'"
- `request.COOKIES.get(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME)` returns None
- `request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', '')` returns "en"
- `django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request(request)` returns "en"
- `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to "de"
- `django.utils.translation.get_language()` returns "de"

Still wondering why 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' is not used - but I will fix this manually by activating the language returned by `get_language_from_request(request) ...

Comment: note the q value.// Multiple types, weighted with the quality value syntax:
Accept-Language: fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5

Comment: I have tested with the "Quick Accept Language Switcher" Plugin of Firefox. There I have entered the language code "en". So there is just "en", no weigh or whatsoever.